# Revert "find . -exec rm -rf {} \;" in NTFS

Tags: linux, ntfs, rm

I accidentally deleted a bunch of files with
`find . -exec rm -rf {} \;` from an NTFS filesystem.

I have unmounted it and tried to use `ntfsundelete` to restore them, but there are too many files to restore them one-by-one. I have noticed that I can see which directory the files are in (`nftsundelete --parent --verbose`), but this only lists the direct parent of the files, not their original path.

Is there a command for NTFS that says "restore all deleted files (ideally to their original location) that were contained in /a/b/c or a subdirectory of /a/b/c"?

Comment: If you will see the output of `nftsundelete --parent --verbose`, for some files it says `Parent: <non-determined>`. Hence even if you get a method to do so, you can't trust that it will recover all recoverable files, that were in that subdirectory.

Comment: I would not mind if I could only restore part of the data. But in this case, I will just restore everything and see what I need later on.